# Matlab GUI's managebuttons

Tags: user-interface, matlab, refactoring, matlab-guide

I have to maintain a large MATLAB GUI, containing quite a few callback functions, each of which gets called at many points.  At some point, I decided to rename one of the callbacks; in order not to have to go through GUIDE to manually modify each of the UI that calls it, I used the *excellent* `gencode` program to "unwrap" the .fig file, `s/old_name/new_name/g`, and recreate the .fig.

This seems to work well, except for one thing: when clicking on a button in a button group, I got a message telling me that the function `manageButtons` is unknown.  After a bit of googling, I find that `manageButtons` is a nested function in `childAddedCbk`, which, I assume, is called by GUIDE as the GUI is created.  Now, trying to move just `manageButtons` outside to its own, in-the-path file doesn't work either: the `hgroup` passed to it is an `invalid handle object`.

So... does anyone has a workaround for that?  Any of the following will be appreciated:

- changing all the callbacks in a GUI in a semi-automatic way, or
- making the `manageButtons` get a valid handle, or
- having `gencode` not break all that.

Thanks,

Antony

Comment: are you referring to this function: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24447 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can export the FIG + M file to single .m file. You will lose the ability to edit this with guide, but you will be able to do a simple regular expression replace on the resulting .m file.

In order to do so - use on the menu of GUIDE -> File -> Export.